# Using xacro package in ROS 2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using the xacro package in ROS Melodic to convert .xacro's to .urdf's, but I need to use python 3 now and my ROS Melodic is using python 2. I installed ROS 2 Eloquent onto my Windows device, but ROS 2 does not seem to have the xacro package installed. Could I get some help as to how to use xacro in ROS 2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354341/using-xacro-package-in-ros-2/) by [max_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/55618/max_a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-08**:\

> ROS 2 Melodic

just making sure: Melodic is a ROS 1 release name.

**Comment by [max_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/55618/max_a/) on 2020-06-08**:
Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Xacro is released for all recent distros up to and including eloquent.

https://index.ros.org/p/xacro/#eloquent

You didn't clarify what installation method you used on Windows, but I'll assume that you didn't get one that included xacro, ROS 2 is a collection of packages and depending on what installation method you select you get different packages. And not all packages are bundled into the binary packages we built. The quickest way to add xacro is to put it into your source workspace and build it with your packages.

---

It's not yet released for Foxy  If you'd like to see it released there please reach out to the maintainers probably the best way is to request a release on the issue tracker on it's repository: https://github.com/ros/xacro

If you use it from source and validate that it works, and or make any necessary patches it will help make it easier for the maintainers to respond quickly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/55618/max_a/) on 2020-06-08**:
I installed ROS 2 just through this link: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Windows-Install-Binary/, do you know which installation method includes xacro?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-06-08**:
From looking quickly I don't think xacro is currently in the pre-packaged binaries for Windows. I opened a ticket to improve the docuementation here: https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/756

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-06-29**:
As a follow-up, we've documented that fat binary installations only contain a subset of packages (https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/802). With this installation method, you should build packages that are not included, like xacro, from source.

**Comment by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on 2021-05-07**:
For the record: xacro has been released for foxy by now.